# Mapping several Textures on the same surface

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, texture-mapping, render-to-texture

I am rendering a cylinder and mapping two different textures to the top and to the bottom face.

Both the textures are loaded in the following way:

```
    check3dFloorFile = new File(check3dFloorPath);
    try {
        check3dFloorTexture = TextureIO.newTexture(check3dFloorFile, true);
    } catch (IOException | GLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Viewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
       
    check3dFloorTexture.setTexParameteri(gl, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
                                                   GL2.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    check3dFloorTexture.setTexParameteri(gl, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
                                                                 GL2.GL_LINEAR);
               
    check3dFloorBackFile = new File(check3dFloorBackPath);
           
    try {
        check3dFloorBackTexture = TextureIO.newTexture(check3dFloorBackFile, true);
    } catch (IOException | GLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Viewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
     
    check3dFloorBackTexture.setTexParameteri(gl, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
                                                 GL2.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    check3dFloorBackTexture.setTexParameteri(gl, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
                                                               GL2.GL_LINEAR);
```

The problem arises when I try to render to a texture (a blank one, that has nothing to do with this first two ones):

```
gl.glGenTextures(1, textureID, 0);
gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0]);
    
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST);
    
    // null means reserve texture memory, but texels are undefined
    gl.glTexImage2D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL2.GL_RGB, floorWidth, floorHeight,
                                                0, GL2.GL_RGB, GL2.GL_FLOAT, null);
    
    gl.glGenFramebuffers(1, frameBufferID, 0);
    gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferID[0]);
    
    //Attach 2D texture to this FBO
    gl.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL2.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
                                    GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0], 0);
    
    // depth buffer
    //int[] depthRenderBufferID = new int[1];
    gl.glGenRenderbuffers(1, depthRenderBufferID, 0);
    gl.glBindRenderbuffer(GL2.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferID[0]);
    gl.glRenderbufferStorage(GL2.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL2.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 
                                            floorWidth, floorHeight);
    gl.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL2.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                                        GL2.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferID[0]);
     
   if(gl.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        System.out.println("[Viewer] GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE!!");
    else
        System.out.println("..cazzo ^^");
```

As soon as this code is executed, the texture mapped on the top of the cylinder disappears and all the top turns to black...

Why?

Ps: my task is to map this third rendered texture on the top of the cylinder, over the already existing one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0]);
/*... */
gl.glGenFramebuffers(1, frameBufferID, 0);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferID[0]);

//Attach 2D texture to this FBO
gl.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL2.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
                                GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0], 0);
```

You need to unbind the texture first from the texture target, before a framebuffer it has been attached to can be selected as render target. Since you don't do this, you'll render nothing to that texture thus it will come out blank.

Comment: I dont get it...what do you mean by "texture target"? And how can I unbind?

Comment: call `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);` before calling `glBindFramebuffer`. If the FBO color attachment texture has been bound to several texturing units you must unbind it for each those.

Comment: It is working, I can see that now I am rendering properly on the texture.. (with some special buffer)

The problem is now how I can do to apply two texture on the same surface: at the moment I already mapped the check3dFloorTexture on the top of a cylinder. I would like to add over this one, the texture that I rendered to (and I would need to do this with some special blending function).
How can I do that?

Comment: @elect: Using a method called multitexturing. There are tutorials about it.